# WebApi Custom Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I've been grindign me head over this one.
I've been trying to implement a custom authorize attribute for a WebApi. I've read multiple articles on how to do this, but for some reason the authorization is never executed.

```
public class ActivityAuthorizeWebApiAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string[] Activities { get; set; }
    public string Activity
    {
        set
        {
            this.Activities = value.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
        }
        get { return string.Join(",", this.Activities); }
    }

    public ActivityAuthorizeWebApiAttribute()
    {
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var principalUser = HttpContext.Current.User;
        if (principalUser == null || !principalUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!principalUser.Activities().Any())
        {
            var activityProvider = (IActivityProvider)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IActivityProvider));
            var activities = activityProvider.GetActivitiesByRoleId(principalUser.Identity.GetUserId());
            principalUser.SetActivities(activities);

        }

        return principalUser.HasAnyActivity(this.Activities.ToList());

        //check your permissions
    }

}
```

As i can see i'm inheriting from the correct AuthorizeAtribute, not the mvc one. But the IsAuthorized method is never called.
The controller action

```
[ActivityAuthorizeWebApi(Activity = "Home")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Could it be because of the combination with the bearer token Authentication?

Edit:
I've even tried just this code:

```
public class CustomAuthorize : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
}
```

As custom code, and not authorze is executed.

Comment: even before IsAuthorized OnAutorization method will be called.....I think there might be some condition in OnAuthorizatoin which might be causing to skip ISAuthorized method call......Do one thing override OnAuthorized method and may be call base.OnAuthorized in that method....just do this test to see if breakpoint is hitting in this method

Comment: Even when i override OnAuthorize, OnAuthorize isn't executed. The debugger never breaks in OnAuthorize nor in IsAuthorized

Answer (score 0):

You need to be  hooking into the following methods when you create a custom attribute :

```
 public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)

 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)

 private bool AuthorizeRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
```

Its the **OnAuthorization** Method that youneed to override and perform your security logic. You can get the User from the **actionContext** in the signature method.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute

    {

         public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)

        {

            if (AuthorizeRequest(actionContext))

            {

                return;

            }

            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);

        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)

        {

           //Code to handle unauthorized request

        }

        private bool AuthorizeRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)

        {

            //Write your code here to perform authorization

            return true;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Even when i override the OnAuthorize method, OnAuthorize isn't executed. The debugger never breaks in OnAuthorize() nor in IsAuthorized(). I tried that before, and tried it again just now.